# Search for redundant filters(channels) in CNN

Tags: cnn, dimensionality-reduction, pruning

When training a `CNN` one specifies in each layer the number of channels. In the input we have 1 channel for grayscale image and 3 for RGB image, and then usually the image resolution is decreased, whereas the number of channels increases (64, 128, 512).

These filters capture some patterns, useful for solving a particular task - classification, segmentation, detection, whatever. However, the resulting collection of numbers in the filter does not have a particular structure, and I may happen, and I suppose, mostly happens, that there is a lot of redundancy in the channels.

If one is interested to make the `CNN` as small as possible in order to use less memory or speedup inference procedure, what are the best procedures to eliminate the redundant, useless filters?

One possibility I see is to measure the correlation between different channels in ordet to determine, whether they are linearly dependent. But I suppose, that It can get help to get rid only of very limited number of channels.

Another possibility, I would think about us to perform `variational dropout` https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.05369.pdf but a filterwise version to determine *noisy* channels. And then eliiminate them.

Third, since filters are $N$-dimensional arrays, there exist certain decompositions, namely HOSVD  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition. But the layers are connected with each other, and truncation needs to be performed in some self-consistent way.

Which approaches turned out to be succesful in CNN and CV tasks?